# How to setup Webpack, babel for simple project in JS and HTML

Tags: npm, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I want to setup ES6, babel and Webpack for my simple project in html and Javascript. Can please anybody point me to right direction.

I am using windows as my OS.

Comment: sample are here : https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples  docs are here : https://webpack.js.org/configuration/   try running some of the examples from samples and try reading the docs